# Ho to take photo with flashlight in Camera2 Api

Tags: android, android-camera2

Could you explain me how can I take picture with flashlight in Camera2. I used

```
captureRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
        cameraCaptureSession?.setRepeatingRequest(
            captureRequestBuilder!!.build(),
            captureCallback,
            backgroundHandler
)
```

but this code turns on flashlight every time and do not stop

Comment: You want flashlight to turn on only when picture is captured?

Comment: @Agnohendrix yes only when I tap on button to capture image

Comment: You should add your code because this might change based on where you put your code. Anyway you should call `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);` somewhere after your call to capture method.